# Tafsir of a hadith regarding to stop reading Quran

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

I agree that the meaning of this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/92) (below) is clear, for me, it is geared towards unity in Islam. However, my question is, **is there any official tafsir of it from classical Ulama ?**

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Recite (and study) the Qur'an as long as
>   your hearts are in agreement as to its meanings, but if you have
>   differences as regards its meaning, stop reading it then."
>   (Sahih al-Bukhari 7365)

Comment: Just a question can you explain what exactly it is saying by if you have disagreements stop reading it?

Comment: Well, it's not disagreements but there are things that can be interpreted in different ways, for example, stop reading it-> stop reading it completely, stop reading it together, stop reading together exactly where you differ. Or the whole hadith can be interpreted differently, the hadith could be a metaphor to say that difference can occur on the most important sources so differences can occur on any matter of religion but mslims should remain united whatever the difference, well there are countless other ways of interpreting it.

Comment: What you say in the comment comes close to the meaning as interpreted by scholars however one reason for disagreement at the time was the difference in usage of the words and their meaning as the qur'an was reveals in seven ahruf.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, so if i understand, this hadith was revealed in this context, can we use it it a context where people differs in other matters, so as to put forth and emphasis of the importance of unity ?